# QGIS Points in Polygon Crashes (with data)

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

New to QGIS, using 2.14.0 on Windows 7

I am trying to run **Vector** -> **Analysis Tools** -> **Points in Polygon...** on [these data](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8tQJCb7UMEhZUNmczhCNUhMV0U&usp=sharing). I want to get the *PNTCNT* and summary statistics on the *Amount* attribute. However, every time I run **Points in Polygon...**, I get a "crash dumped" error after reaching 99%:

[image: Crash Dump Error when running **Points in Polygon**]

The only other relevant question I've seen regarding this issue didn't have much in the way of responses. It did have a question in response asking if each layer was a shapefile. In my instance I am trying **Points in Polygon...** with a shapefile and a .csv layer. I'm not sure if that may be my problem. However, I tried saving my delimited layer as a shapefile and trying this again, with no luck.

Also, I've tried **Vector** -> **Data Management Tools** -> **Join Attributes by Location...** and I get a Python error (screenshot with data).

This all leads me to wonder if there is an issue in my data.

Comment: Wanted to reproduce your error messages, but I am missing the vector menu in my 2.14.0 installation (in 2.8.7 on another maschine its present). But running the _Count points in polygon_ tool from processing toolbox raises errors on missing CRS, even if EPSG:4326 is shown. OGR protocol says: invalid datasource, DelimitedText log says: Errors in line 246, 248 (there are invalid coordinates). Have you tried to save both dataset as new layers, and tested again?

Comment: I have now. Unfortunately, no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Detlev suggested, you should re-save **both** your layers but this doesn't fully solve the problem as I tested your shapefiles and still received the error. Therefore I suggest to do the following:

1. Re-save **both** layers to the same CRS using the `Save As...` option (I added the prefix `"NEW_"` which can be seen in the images below).
2. Use the GRASS algorithm **v.clean** from the *Processing Toolbox* with the following parameters on your polygon shapefile:

   [image: GRASS v.clean]

   *Note that this may take a while (took my computer about 20 minutes)*.
3. Now run the **Count points in polygon** tool from the *Processing Toolbox* using the `Cleaned` shapefile as polygons:

   [image: Count points in polygon]
4. You should now have the polygon shapefile with a new `NUMPOINTS` field (or whatever you named it) in the attribute table:

   [image: Results]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, I can't get v.clean to run on my shapefile. The log seems to be telling me I have an invalid N latitude, so I've tried selecting the region/extend on canvas. When I select a large enough area, the algorithm runs further, but throws the following: Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Cleaned
Errors
If you were able to clean the .shp, would you mind sticking it [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8tQJCb7UMEhZUNmczhCNUhMV0U&usp=sharing) for me to try?

Comment: @twgardner2 - Weird, but I've uploaded the cleaned shapefile and the results of what I obtained =)

Comment: Thank you! Just to let you know, I was able to get my .shp cleaned by importing it into GRASS. I'm not really sure what I was doing, but I got a file I could run **Point in Polygon...** on back in QGIS. It resulted in the same partial results you got above. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @twgardner2 - Most welcome! And atleast you got the same results in the end :)